# C++20 out-of-class definition in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Up until C++20 standard of C++, when we wanted to define an out-of-class operator which uses some private members of a template class, we'd use a construct similar to this:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool operator==(T lhs, const Foo<T>& rhs);

template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    constexpr Foo(T k) : mK(k) {}

    constexpr friend bool operator==<T>(T lhs, const Foo& rhs);

private:
    T mK;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool operator==(T lhs, const Foo<T>& rhs) {
    return lhs == rhs.mK;
}

int main() {
    return 1 == Foo<int>(1) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Since C++20, however, we can omit the out-of-class declaration, thus also the forward declaration, so we can get away with just:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    constexpr Foo(T k) : mK(k) {}

    constexpr friend bool operator==<T>(T lhs, const Foo& rhs);
private:
    T mK;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool operator==(T lhs, const Foo<T>& rhs) {
    return lhs == rhs.mK;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8BK6rl)</kbd>

Now, my question is, what part of C++20 allows us to do so? And why wasn't this possible in earlier C++ standards?

---

*As it was pointed out in the comments, clang doesn't accept this code presented in the demo, which suggests this might actually be a bug in gcc.*

***I filed a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93807) on gcc's bugzilla***

Comment: I personally prefer in class definition, avoiding template function (and deduction "issues" (No match for `"c string" == Foo<std::string>("foo")`)).

Comment: @Jarod42 I totally agree, I prefer in-class definition, too. I was just surprised to find out that C++20 allows us not to repeat the function signature three times when defining it ouf-of-class, which may be useful in a public API where the implementation is in a hidden .inl file.

Comment: I haven't noticed it was impossible. How come I've used it thus far without issues?

Comment: Hmmm, in [temp.friend](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend), not much changed, especially not [1.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#1.3) which should be responsible for this behavior. Since clang does _not_ accept your code, I am leaning towards gcc having a bug.

Comment: @ALX23z It works without the out-of-class declaration if the class is not templated.

Comment: @n314159 Ah, that would explain a lot! If there's no other explanation, I'll file a bug report to gcc. I'll wait till the evening to see if someone can clear this up a bit more/confirm that this is, indeed, a bug.

Comment: @ProXicT probably because I also use MSVC. They handle templates compilation differently.

Comment: @ALX23z That was until C++17, if I recall correctly, since then they added the `/permissive-` flag with which the compiler is much closer to the C++17 standard. But I also remember there was still a lot of bugs regarding templates :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC has a bug.

Name lookup is always performed for template names appearing before a `<`, even when the name in question is the name being declared in a (friend, explicit specialization, or explicit instantiation) declaration.

Because the name `operator==` in the friend declaration is an unqualified name and is subject to name lookup in a template, the two-phase name lookup rules apply. In this context, `operator==` is not a dependent name (it's not part of a function call, so ADL does not apply), so the name is looked up and bound at the point where it appears (see [temp.nondep] paragraph 1). Your example is ill-formed because this name lookup finds no declaration of `operator==`.

I would expect GCC is accepting this in C++20 mode due to [P0846R0](http://wg21.link/p0846r0), which permits (for example) `operator==<T>(a, b)` to be used in a template even if no prior declaration of `operator==` as a template is visible.

Here's an even more interesting testcase:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo;

#ifdef WRONG_DECL
template <typename T> bool operator==(Foo<T> lhs, int); // #1
#endif

template <typename T> struct Foo {
  friend bool operator==<T>(Foo<T> lhs, float); // #2
};

template <typename T> bool operator==(Foo<T> lhs, float); // #3
Foo<int> f;
```

With `-DWRONG_DECL`, GCC and Clang agree that this program is ill-formed: unqualified lookup for the friend declaration #2, in the context of the template definition, finds the declaration #1, which doesn't match the instantiated friend of `Foo<int>`. Declaration #3 is not even considered, because unqualified lookup in the template doesn't find it.

With `-UWRONG_DECL`, GCC (in C++17 and earlier) and Clang agree that this program is ill-formed for a different reason: unqualified lookup for `operator==` on line #2 finds nothing.

But with `-UWRONG_DECL`, GCC in C++20 mode appears to decide that it's OK that unqualified lookup for `operator==` in #2 fails (presumably due to P0846R0), and then appears to redo the lookup from the template instantiation context, now finding #3, in violation of the normal two-phase name lookup rule for templates.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation, very well put!